# Why am i Unable to install packages for android

Tags: android

Hello all
Thanks for your previous replies
hey i am unable to install the package Google API's, revision 2...
whenevr i select the third party repository...all the add ons except Google API get selected
Plz help me out as i am working on a location based application....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check with this reference, it meet your requirements.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

http://code.google.com/apis/gears/install.html

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: I am following the instructions right, but still the problem is not solved